# Action performed sitting on a chair that rotates

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases

The question just popped out on seeing my colleague who sits next to me. He always keeps **rotating** sitting on the chair. Well, not a complete *rotation*. Since it is not a full rotation, all I can think of is to call it *oscillating*, since he rotates (oscillates) to his right and left having his feet on the floor, but I am not sure if that person can understand when I say, "Hey, can you not *oscillate* for some time?". This is because I don't know if *oscillation* can be used for used for a movement that happens in a circular fashion.

Is there an exact term/phrase for this action? I don't think *shaking* would be a good fit either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He keeps swiveling in his chair.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swivel

"She swiveled in her seat to check the time.
She swiveled the chair around to face us."

http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/workspaces/20653/

swivel chairs